# How can you mortgage a house owned by a family trust?

Tags: trusts, new-zealand

My wife and I are doing some planning, and one of the options that has been suggested to us is to put the family home in a family trust. There seems to be no problem having a mortgage on the house when we do so, which is confusing me. Since one of the advantages of a trust (as it's been explained to us) is protection from creditors, why would a bank lend us money when they can't collect the security if we default?

Comment: [Some info about it here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/can-put-home-mortgage-family-trust-40600.html).  Basically, some lenders will invoke the "repayment on sale" clause and some won't.

Comment: That's my question. Why would a bank *not* ask for their money back when the property securing the mortgage can no longer be sold in case of default?

Comment: [Well, because you’re still on the hook for it.](http://info.legalzoom.com/house-not-paid-for-can-put-living-trust-25306.html)

Comment: @RupertMorrish Why would you say the house can no longer be sold in case of default? The right to foreclose on the home wouldn't change until/unless the mortgage is paid off.

Answer (score 2):

The asset protection part of a trust is to protect your assets from creditors who have no security in your personal assets

However a Mortgage from your bank on a house owned by a trust, is still secured to that Asset, so there is asset protection available here.

If you default on the mortgage payments then the bank can still take your family home.

Comment: Can you give us some explanation of how the bank could reposses a house owned by someone else, or obtain the lien in the first place?

Comment: @DJClayworth If they couldn't, they wouldn't put the mortgage in place. It would just be a regular unsecured loan [which may be what needs to happen, but the bank won't be tricked into taking security on a non-securable asset].

Comment: Exactly. This answer seems to be describing a situation which can't happen.  Or have I missed something?